# TableView cell is not convertible to Void

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Im having an issue returning a cell from the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I keep getting the error `TableViewCell is not convertible to void` this is something new to me as I've never gotten this error when messing around with cells before. heres my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell
    cell.userName.text = object?.valueForKey("FBName") as? String
    let userProfilePhotoURLString = object?.valueForKey("pictureURL") as? String

    var pictureURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: userProfilePhotoURLString!)!
    var urlRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: pictureURL)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (NSURLResponse response, NSData data,NSError error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            cell.userImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }

    cell.ratingsView.show(rating: 4.0, text: nil)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are returning `UITableViewCell` from `sendAsynchronousRequest` `handler` closure. The closure has return type of `void`.

Your current approach with doing asynchronous request in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is flawed as cell will return before the asynchronous request could be completed.

You should instead do the asynchronous request, update the model when its completed and then reload the table view.